# Laravel HTML Images How to create master page with multiple image tags ..

Tags: php, laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

In master Layout I am trying to do like this

```
          <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                 {{HTML::image('@yield('image0')','@yield('alt0')')}}
                  <div class="carousel-caption">

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                 {{HTML::image('@yield('image1')','@yield('alt1')')}}
                  <div class="carousel-caption">

                 </div>
                 <div class="item">
                  {{HTML::image('@yield('image2')','@yield('alt2')')}}
                  <div class="carousel-caption">

                  </div> 
                 <div class="item">
                 {{HTML::image('@yield('image3')','@yield('alt3')')}}
                  <div class="carousel-caption">

                  </div>
                 <div class="item">
                  {{HTML::image('@yield('image4')','@yield('alt4')')}}
                  <div class="carousel-caption">

                  </div> 
                  </div>
                 <div class="item">
                  {{HTML::image('@yield('image5')','@yield('alt5')')}}
                  <div class="carousel-caption">

                  </div> 
                </div>
```

In Page

@extends('tours/toursMaster')

@section('title','Some title')
@section('image0','assets/IG_101/IG1011.jpg')

.......
................

But the error I am encountering is

syntax error, unexpected 'image0' (T_STRING)

```
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
              </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                 <?php echo HTML::image('<?php echo $__env->yieldContent('image0'); ?>','<?php echo $__env->yieldContent('alt0'); ?>'); ?>
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
```

Note :I am using Codesleeve asset pipeline 
         and my Images are in respective folders..

Answer (score 0):

You've an error in the HTML::image(
You can solve this:

```
 <?php echo HTML::image($__env->yieldContent('image0'),$__env->yieldContent('alt0')); ?>
```

Hope this will work for you.

You can't echo some content into an php function. If you want to print something to the browser then you've to use functions like `print, echo or (s)printf`. But in this case you would like to pass some content to a php function and not to the user. So therefore you've to give a reference to a existing variable to the `HTML::image` method. So you only have to use echo or something like that if you want to print that. In this case you only wants to print the `HTML::image(...);` result.

Hope its clear for you!

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand
laravel I am using @yield in master layout to get the image